# Multiplying large matrices in Python 3

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a homework that involves Python code and multiplying some Numpy arrays of length 100, but the following error comes up:

```
ValueError: maximum supported dimension for an ndarray is 32, found 100
```

Here's my code, xs and ys are two lists of length 100.

```
%inline pylab

import numpy as np

Y = np.array(ys).reshape(len(ys),1)
X = np.array([len(xs)*[1],xs]).transpose()
B = linalg.inv(X.transpose().dot(X)).dot(X.transpose(X)).dot(Y)
```

Comment: Hi Ronan, your code won't run. It's missing the definitions for xs, ys, linalg is not imported anywhere.

Adding my own arrays xs, ys of length 100 wasn't enough to make it run either.

Could you please add a minimum working example to your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i guess you just have a typo in `X.transpose(X)` -> `linalg.inv(X.transpose().dot(X)).dot(  X.transpose(X)      ).dot(Y)`
I don't think you really want to specify the *axes along which to transpose as "X"

not sure what you're trying to compute but probably `X.transpose()` is what you mean or maybe you wanted `X.transpose().dot(X)` ..

Comment: You're correct, it was a typo in defining B, I've learned something new about transpose! Thank you very much :)